# Fortran data declaration, MATLAB translation

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have to translate in MATLAB this Fortran statement (variable initialization):

```
data k/350*'  '/
```

where `k` was declared like

```
character*2 k(31,12)
```

I have read that `*` is equal to comma, that is to say `k` will be an array of two elements, 350 and an empty cell?

What should I write in MATLAB? This `k=['350',''];`?

Comment: If you want to enter `350` as a number then `k={350, [] }`. If you want to enter `350` as a string then `k={'350',[]}` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html

Comment: It is declared as "character*2 k(31,12)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `data` statement `*` is not the same as `,`: `,` is a separator, but `*` is a repeat count specifier.

The example of the question

```
character*2 k(31,12)
data k/350*'  '/
```

has the initialization value equal to 700 blanks and `k` is a rank-2 array (of shape `[31,12]`) of length-2 characters.

Ideally, the size of `k` would be identical to the size of the initialization value expression but there is a difference: 744, and 700.  Let's just assume that the intention is that each element of the array `k` has value `'  '` (ie., all blanks).

As to the best way of doing that in MATLAB, I'm no expert.  But if necessary I'll add a way (or someone else can).  Hopefully the explanation of what the Fortan code is (intended to do/) doing is sufficient.

Comment: If I got it, k is declared as an empty matrix 31*12. I think there's a mistake in the code, 350 sholud be 372 and every value of the matrix is empty.

Comment: I think the best way in matlab is k=zeros(31,12); This has to be done only if I have to "fill" the empty spaces with a incremental loop: only in this case it useful to preallocate the memory.

Comment: `372*'  '` would indeed be correct.  Given, I believe, character variables in MATLAB are initialized to blank you just have to declare a string as an array of the appropriate size and length.

Comment: In matlab, a good way to initialize k would be as a cell array `k=repmat({'  '},31,12)` There are fortran statements that depend on the length (2 in this case) of the array so it is useful to initialize the cells in matlab to actual spaces. f2matlab from the file exchange can help with converting fortran source to matlab/octave source.